# Do want or need a "plot inconsistency" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since we don't really like questions about plot inconsistencies (they tend to get closed as "opinion based"), do we want the newly minted tag https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but "we don't really like questions about plot inconsistencies" is an assertion without any proof and is 100% false.

There may be some members of the community who don't like them (and try to close them by applying entirely unwarranted "opinion based" despite the OP seeking a fact based in-universe answer).

But based on Meta, questions about plot inconsistencies are generally on-topic. Since it was discussed previously ([[1]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/957/usefulness-of-plot-hole-answers-comments), [[2]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed),[[3]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2670/976),[[4]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1092/976),[[5]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/are-too-many-people-afraid-to-use-plot-device-instead-of-resorting-to-speculat) - some explicitly discuss the in-scopeness of plot hole questions; and some simply discuss how to answer such questions which by omission of "this isn't in scope" validates the question being in-scope) I won't devote space and time to re-hashing it.

As such, the tag is perfectly fine based on your reasoning.

However, we already have a tag [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) which IMHO fully encompasses anything that [plot-inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency) does, so the latter may be a good idea to be a synonym of the former.

Comment: Certainly false; Forgotten Phlebotinum would fall under such Plot Inconsistency, but asking a question about it [can result in an unexpected answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/why-only-use-sevens-nano-probes-to-revive-neelix)